# prevent destroying component state on routing, without using RouteReuseStrategy

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-services, angular-routing

I researched about this topic and found that RouterReuseStrategy is a solution but i cant use RouterReuse How do i prevent destroying component state without using the RouterReuse Solution

Please consider upvoting becoz it will help get the answers.

// app.module.ts

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'registration', component: RegistrationComponent },
  { path: 'users', component: ListComponent },
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    Capitalize,
    FilterPipe,
    ListComponent,
    RegistrationComponent,
    PageNotFoundComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    FormsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

// app.component.html

```
<section class="container">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div>    
        <a class="navbar-brand" routerLink="/">Brand</a>
      </div>  
      <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a routerLink="/">Home</a></li>
          <li><a routerLink="/registration">Registration</a></li>
          <li><a routerLink="/users">Users</a></li>                    
        </ul>        
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</section>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

[stackblitzLink](https://angular-akfgzn.stackblitz.io)

Comment: Honestly, *i dont want to use RouterReuse* doesn't sound like a very good reason.

Comment: updated the stackblitz link

Comment: The link doesn't contain a workable application. The question doesn't state why exactly you don't use RouterReuseStrategy. If you have problems with using it, it should say what are these problems and not request a way to avoid it.

Comment: The correct way to do this is to use RouteReuseStrategy, you can check this article for starters, https://medium.com/@gerasimov.pk/64628e1ca3eb . Also, [Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I believe my answer answers the question and explains the options. If you will have specific problems implementing it, consider asking a question that explains them and shows your current attempt.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the state in a service that is provided on a level that is not recreated on routing, for example in AppModule or AppComponent.

Also if **only** the navigation only changes route params, but stays on the same route, components are not recreated and therefore you won't lose the state. But that works only for specific use cases.

Comment: can you please write an answer with some more details please

Comment: do you got a minute can we discuss this over chat

Comment: I don't know how to go to the chat if it's not suggested to switch to chat. Please just provide some information about what is unclear.

Comment: i actually have a code. where i used a service to pass data to two diffrent views. but on routing the the component state is destroyed. having trouble fixing that. If you could look into that code. that be really great

Comment: its actually a form where user submits the data. that data gets passed to the service and then its passed to the view component. i cant seem to find how do i prevent state change on routnig

Comment: can i share it over team viewer

Comment: Sorry, I don't have that much time. Please create a reduces example in stackblitz and I'll have a look.

Comment: give me two minutes ill try to post it on stackblitz.

Comment: sorry i tried adding to stackbltz but i dont think you can clone a git repository into that. there are lots of files and i dont know how to create a reduced version

Comment: I'm not interested in looking at a Git repository anyway. Reduce the code to the absolute minimum required to reproduce the issue. This doesn't require more than 3 simple components (AppComponent, the component with the form, and some other component to route to/away)

Comment: I only get a white page from your stackblitz link with the error message `Uncaught (in promise) Error: reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators`. Can you please try to open the page from your line in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Preserving route component state is one of several problems that `RouteReuseStrategy` is supposed to solve.

The alternative is to keep state outside of component instance, i.e. in separate provider. A developer can control which injector this provider will belong to and thus when provider instance will be destroyed.

```
@Component(
  ...
  template: `{{ state.bar }}`
)
class FooComponent {
  constructor(public state: FooState) {}
}
```

If state provider was defined in parent component, it will be destroyed when parent component is destroyed. If it was defined as module provider, it won't be destroyed at all.

Of course, if there are several `FooComponent` instances, they will share the state. If this isn't desirable behaviour then again, `RouteReuseStrategy` should be used instead.

Also, state management libraries like [`ngrx`](https://github.com/ngrx/platform) allow to manage states more efficiently.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. can you please take a look at my code through teamviewer

Comment: SO rules require to provide http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve in the question itself. Consider providing workable example via Plunker or Stackblitz.